# PORTB and PINB in avr studio while programming for Atmega8?

Tags: atmega

what is the difference between PORTB and PINB in avr studio while programming for Atmega8 using " Atmel Studio.6 " software ??

Comment: No research effort! Question should be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a massive amount of difference.  Those differences are most noticeable when the pin is in input mode (DDRxn = 0).

When in input mode:

PINxn reads the value of the IO pin as it is at the actual pin itself.
PORTxn controls the pull-up resistor.

When in output mode:

PORTxn sets the pin output level.  PINxn reads that pin output level.

It's all explained in the datasheet.  The simplest thing is to look at the diagram of how an IO port works:

[image]

From that you can see that PINxn gets its value direct from the IO pin itself, and PORTxn sends its output to the IO pin and also to the gate that controls the pullup resistor.

Reading from PINxn will always read the raw pin, though, and reading from PORTxn will always read the value before the DDRxn buffer.  Thus, in input mode, reading PINxn will read the pin value, and reading PORTxn will read the pullup resistor state.  In output mode reading either PINxn or PORTxn will return the value being driven by the PORTxn register.

So in general - if you are outputting, write to PORTxn. If you are inputting, read from PINxn.